# Run npm build after beanstalk deploy

Tags: node.js, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Anyone know how to get node AWS beanstalk to run npm run build command after its does its npm install.

I have the following scripts in my package.json but it doesn't seem to run the build or the start command just the install

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config ./webpack/webpack.prod.config.js --progress --colors",
    "start": "node server/app.js",
    "dev": "nodemon server/app.js"
  },
```

Comment: Please share your `eb-activity.log` and `eb-commandprocessor.log` in order to get more information about this error.

Comment: These logs are huge, how would you like me to share them. They are way to long to just paste in the post

Comment: you can post the failure message and couple of lines before or use `https://pastebin.com/` and share here the link

Comment: Thanks Berlin. eb_activity https://pastebin.com/0v86kH6g

Comment: command processor https://pastebin.com/JNWF2rSM

Comment: Berlin did you get a chance to go through the logs I sent ?

Comment: are you using some shell script `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/50npm.sh` in your `.ebextensions`, can you share also your full `.ebextensions` files ?